# How to show record int profile related to user using Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to show record into user's profile related to user. I am trying to do this unfortunately it's not showing record related to user. How to do this?

**Database**

```
        digitizing_orders table has user_id
```

**Digitizingorder**

```
                    class Digitizingorder extends Model
                    {
                          protected $table="digitizing_orders";

                          public function user()
                          {
                          return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
                          }
                    }
```

**User Model**

```
                     class User extends Authenticatable
                     {
                        public function digitizing()
                        {
                        return $this->hasMany('App\Digitizingorder','user_id');
                        }
                      }
```

**controller**

```
                 public function index()
                 {
                 $data=
                  [
                 'digitizings'=>Digitizingorder::with('user')->where('id','=',Auth::id())->get()
                   ];
                   return view('front_end.Customerprofile.digitizing_view_order',$data);
                 }
                       

                       @foreach($digitizings  as   $digitizing)
                          <tr>
                          <td>1</td>
                          <td>DPO-{{$digitizing->id}}</td>
                          <td>{{$digitizing->order_name}}</td>
                          <td>{{$digitizing->created_at}}</td>
                          <td>-</td>
                          <td>$0.00</td>           
                          </tr>
                          @endforeach
```

Comment: if Auth::id() is logged in user's id then in query you should use user_id  Digitizingorder::with('user')->where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a `hasMany` relationship you can get digitizings like so:

```
  public function index()
             {
             $data=
              [
             'digitizings'=>Auth::user()->digitizing()->get()
               ];
               return view('front_end.Customerprofile.digitizing_view_order',$data);
             }
```

This will get the orders for the authenticated user.